# Password validation using PHP

Tags: php

I have this script that determines if a password fits my criteria or not. It detects everything but the `+` ...

Can any one tell me why this is the case?

```
    <?php

    //include('database_connection.php');
    //Include The Database Connection File 

    function pwd_contents($pwd, $notAllowedChar)
    {
        $pass_array = str_split($pwd);
        $notAllowedChar_array = str_split($notAllowedChar);

        foreach($notAllowedChar_array as $nChar)
        {
            if(in_array($nChar, $pass_array))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['password']))//If a username has been submitted 
    {
        $pattern = '/\/@\+\=\#\*/';
        $password = $_POST['password'];//Some clean up :)

        if(pwd_contents($password, $pattern))
            echo '1';
        else
            echo '0';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you specifying your notallowedchars as a regex, and then using split/loops to actually compare? A simple `if (preg_match($pwd, $notAllowedChar)) { die("Illegal char"); }` would do ALL of what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Don't know... why not skip the str_split on $notAllowedChar and just pass the array to pwd_contents e.g. $pattern = array("/", "\", "@", "+", "-", "*")?

Comment: Why limit password characters? This just limit user password strongness. You should only limit password length to fit in your database.